# Calling a function within a procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I apologize ahead of time for the probably basic question.  I am student and it is crunch time!

I am using Oracle 10g Express.

I created a function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION test_glaccounts_description
(
account_description_param VARCHAR2
) 
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  description_dup_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO description_dup_var
  FROM general_ledger_accounts
  WHERE account_description = account_description_param;

  RETURN description_dup_var;  
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

And would like to use that function in a procedure.
I've tried:

```
PROCEDURE insert_gla_with_test
(
  account_number_param  NUMBER,
  account_description_param VARCHAR2
)
 AS
BEGIN 
  IF test_glaccounts_description = 1 THEN
  INSERT INTO  general_ledger_accounts
  VALUES (account_number_param, account_description_param);
  ELSE raise_application_error (-20001, 'Duplicate account description');
  END IF;
END;
```

But it doesn't like the "test_gla_accounts" line.....what am I doing wrong?
To my understanding, the function returns a value of 1 or 0, in the procedure, if the function returned a 1, I would like the param fields added to the table.  If the function returned a 0, I would like the procedure to raise the error.

Comment: It is always helpful to post the full error stack.  Saying something like "it doesn't like" doesn't tell us what error you are getting.  I guessed at the error in my answer below.  If I guessed incorrectly (there could be more syntax errors, for example), posting the full error stack will be very useful.

Answer (score 4):

`test_glaccounts_description` takes a parameter (`account_description_param`) and returns a `NUMBER`.  In order to call the function, therefore, you need to pass in a parameter.  Assuming that you want to pass in the `account_description_param` that is passed in to the `insert_gla_with_test` procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_gla_with_test
(
  account_number_param  NUMBER,
  account_description_param VARCHAR2
)
 AS
BEGIN 
  IF test_glaccounts_description( account_description_param ) = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO  general_ledger_accounts
      VALUES (account_number_param, account_description_param);
  ELSE 
    raise_application_error (-20001, 'Duplicate account description');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thanks so much for the quick and helpful response....I worked on that for many hours already!